# Dell 1950 (MegaRAID SAS 1078) refuses to add spare

Tags: raid, dell

I needed to replace a Dell R300 machine (Running Ubuntu Linux) which had failed, and had a Dell 1950 (with MegaRAID SAS 1078) laying around. It initially worked; I moved the drives and it recognized it as a foreign array and did a background init. Now after a few days, the second disk has been kicked out. And for the life of me, I can't add it again. It keeps saying cryptic things like:

[image]

[image]

I tried taking the disks out, resetting the controller config, re-adding the disks. I also zeroed the start and end of the hotspare, but to no avail.

The ctrl-r screen basically only has one option, and that is setting a new disk as global spare, which obviously doesn't work. I'm clueless what this could be.

Edit: after upgrading the firmware to 1.22.32-1371 (using a bootable ISO that tries 115 firmwares), I got one minuscule step forward: I can now select a disk group and set a spare (as opposed to only a global one), but now I get this helpful message:

[image]

Edit2: after taking the disks out, resetting the controller config, and re-importing the foreign config, it gave another unclear error why that was not possible, and I wasn't even able to start a degraded array anymore.

Luckily the array meta data is at the end of the disk, so I can see a partition table when putting the drive in my USB drive bay. I'm `dd`'ing an image now, and will just re-create an array and use sysrescue CD to recover the image.

Hooray for Linux MD software RAID. You can restore an array in a kitchen sink if you'd want, as long as it has SATA connectors.

Comment: What about firmware? Is it the latest?

Comment: @JaroslavKucera I upgraded it (took a lot of work). See above.

Comment: Did you update the disk firmware as well?

Comment: @dyasny no, I had to give up. See edit.

Comment: What you've got there is either a faulty disk or a gross perc/hdd firmware mismatch. I've literally "fixed" thousands of such failures by ensuring the fw levels were right.